# Can I debug my Kotlin code in CLion/Xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, kotlin, kotlin-native

I compiled my `Kotlin` code to a dynamic library and used it in a `C++` project. I'm wondering is there any way to debug my `Kotlin` code in the `C++` project? According the official reference(https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/native/debugging.html), I can use `lldb` or `gdb` to debug my `Kotlin` code, but it's inconvenient. What I want is debugging code directly in IDE(such as XCode and CLion). Thanks for your replying!

Comment: Is it posible to install [this plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12775-native-debugging-support) in CLion?

Answer (score 0):

We publish a plugin for Xcode that lets you debug Kotlin/Native code in the editor: https://github.com/touchlab/xcode-kotlin